# Is there a default password to connect to vagrant when using `homestead ssh` for the first time?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I'm trying to connect to vagrant via `homestead ssh`:

```
vagrant@127.0.0.1's password:
```

But my public key password doesn't work.
My Homestead.yaml looks like this:

```
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I'm using "Laravel Homestead version 2.0.14" with "Vagrant 1.7.2".

Answer (score 282, accepted):

After trying a lot of passwords and becoming totally confused why my public key password is not working I found out that I have to use `vagrant` as password.

Maybe this info helps someone else too - that's because I've written it down here.

***Edit:***
According to the Vagrant documentation, there is *usually* a default password for the user `vagrant` which is `vagrant`.
Read more on here: [official website](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/base.html#default-user-settings)

In recent versions however, they have moved to generating keypairs for each machine. If you would like to find out where that key is, you can run `vagrant ssh -- -v`. This will show the verbose output of the ssh login process. You should see a line like

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/aaron/Documents/VMs/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
```

Comment: Thanks, this saved my day on Windows machine where I already had authorization keys for Git which could not be used by Putty without dealing with conversion tools etc. One more confusion factor was insecure_private_key of Vagrant itself which turned out to be unused by Homestead, but I didn't realize that and spent much time figuring out which key should I use. So finally I just gave up and used `vagrant` password, as you suggested.

Comment: As of today, the credentials are: vagrant for user and for password.

Answer (score 18):

I've a same problem. After move machine from restore of Time Machine, on another host. There problem it's that ssh key for vagrant it's not your key, it's a key on Homestead directory.

Solution for me:

- Use vagrant / vagrant for access ti VM of Homestead
- vagrant ssh-config for see config of ssh

run on terminal

```
vagrant ssh-config
Host default
HostName 127.0.0.1
User vagrant
Port 2222
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile "/Users/MYUSER/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
IdentitiesOnly yes
LogLevel FATAL
ForwardAgent yes
```

Create a new pair of SSH keys

```
ssh-keygen -f /Users/MYUSER/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
```

Copy content of public key

```
cat /Users/MYUSER/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key.pub
```

On other shell in Homestead VM Machine copy into authorized_keys

```
vagrant@homestad:~$ echo 'CONTENT_PASTE_OF_PRIVATE_KEY' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Now can access with vagrant ssh

Comment: this was a great answer; my issue when connecting was that I had selected the wrong identity-file, the IdentityFile listing in `vagrant ssh-config` is the correct path

Answer (score 13):

By default Vagrant uses a generated private key to login, you can try this:

```
ssh -l ubuntu -p 2222 -i .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 11):

This is the default working setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiD7JTCBdpI

Use Connection Method: `standard TCP/IP over ssh`

Then ssh hostname: `127.0.0.1:2222`

SSH Username: `vagrant password vagrant`

MySQL Hostname: `localhost`

Username: `homestead password:secret`

Answer (score 4):

On a Windows machine I was able to log to to ssh from git bash with
 
`ssh vagrant@VAGRANT_SERVER_IP` without providing a password

Using Bitvise SSH client on window
Server host: `VAGRANT_SERVER_IP`
Server port: `22`
Username: `vagrant`
Password: `vagrant`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I learned through the output from:

```
vagrant ssh -- -v
```

The problem was my private key generated by vagrant was ignored because the permissions were too open (on Windows 10).

The log lines were:

> Permissions for 'C:/My Folder/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key'
> are too open. It is required that your private key files are NOT
> accessible by others. This private key will be ignored.

So in Windows Explorer, navigate to the private key for the VM on the path in your log, right-click and select properties. Then go to the Security tab and click the Advanced button. Next, Add your specific user with Full Control, and then select whichever group also has permissions and click the Disable inheritance button at the bottom of the dialog and chose to remove all inheritance. You should be left with just your own user account having permissions on the private_key file. Click Apply and close the properties dialog, then try `vagrant ssh` again. It should now let you in without asking for a password.